# Newton's Method in R Precision/Output

Tags: r

So, I'm supposed to write the code to execute Newton's Method to calculate the square root of any arbitrary number to a specified precision (tolerance).

Here is my code:

```
MySqrt <- function(x, eps = 1e-6, itmax = 100, verbose = TRUE) {
  GUESS <- 11
  myvector <- integer(0)
  i <- 1
  if (x < 0) {
    stop("Square root of negative value")
  }
  else {
    myvector[i] <- GUESS

    while (i <= itmax) {
      GUESS <- (GUESS + (x/GUESS)) * 0.5
      myvector[i+1] <- GUESS

      if (abs(GUESS-myvector[i]) < eps) {
        break()
      } 

      if (verbose) {
        cat("Iteration: ", formatC(i, width = 1), formatC(GUESS, digits = 10, width = 12),     "\n")
      }

      i <- i + 1

    }
  }    
  myvector[i]
}
```

eps is the tolerance. When I use the function to calculate the square root of, say, 21, I got this as an output:

```
> MySqrt(21, eps = 1e-1, verbose = TRUE)
Iteration:  1  6.454545455 
Iteration:  2  4.854033291 
Iteration:  3   4.59016621
```

I'm not sure if the function stops carrying out iterations when it is supposed to, however. Can someone verify if my code is correct? This would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think it is stopping to early?  You asked for a tolerance of a tenth...`all.equal(MySqrt(21, eps=1e-1), sqrt(21), tolerance=1e-1)` is `TRUE`.

Comment: for me it iterated 6 times, printing output 5 times, and it looks the same out to 6 digits as `sqrt(21)`

Comment: > MySqrt(21, 0.01)
Iteration:  1  6.454545455 
Iteration:  2  4.854033291 
Iteration:  3   4.59016621 
[1] 4.590166

Should there be a fourth iteration? The difference between the 2nd and 3rd iteration results is not less than the tolerance level, so the loop should still be executed. But I don't know why it stops at just 3 iterations.

Comment: instead of `myvector[i]`, just return `myvector`, and you'll see the whole thing. It actually iterates 1 more time than it's telling you. It stopped because the absolute difference in the last 2 elements of `myvector` was less than your `eps` of `.01` : `4.590166` vs `4.582582`

Comment: My bad. If we set verbose to TRUE, it would only display up to Iteration 3. The 4th iteration is still not shown.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost correct.  It is iterating the correct number of times.  The only bug is that you don't increment `i` until after the break statement, so you are not returning the most recent approximation.  Instead you are returning the previous one.

In order to verify that it is stopping at the right time, you can move the tracing line up above the break.  You can also add `GUESS-myvector[i]` to the trace, so you can watch it halt as soon as the difference gets small enough.  If you do this and run the function, the fact that it is stopping at the right time, as well as the fact that it is returning the wrong value, will be obvious:

```
> MySqrt(21,eps=1e-1)
Iteration:  1 6.454545 -4.545455 
Iteration:  2 4.854033 -1.600512 
Iteration:  3 4.590166 -0.2638671 
Iteration:  4 4.582582 -0.007584239 
[1] 4.590166
```

While your code is (almost) correct, it is not written in very good R style.  For example, unless you want to return the entire vector of estimates, there is no reason that you need to keep them all around.  Also, rather than using a while loop, here it would make more sense to use a for loop.  Here one possible improved version of your function:

```
MySqrt <- function(x, eps = 1e-6, itmax = 100, verbose = TRUE) {
  GUESS <- 11
  if (x < 0) {
    stop("Square root of negative value")
  }
  for(i in 1:itmax){
      nextGUESS <- (GUESS + (x/GUESS)) * 0.5
      if (verbose)
        cat("Iteration: ", i, nextGUESS, nextGUESS-GUESS, "\n")

      if (abs(GUESS-nextGUESS) < eps) 
        break

      GUESS<- nextGUESS
    }
  nextGUESS
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Still a newbie at R coding, so I'm still surviving off Google's R Style Guide, but you were of great help!